# Product of a logit coefficient and a linear regression coefficient

Tags: logistic, mediation

Suppose I have the following model:

$X \rightarrow M \rightarrow Y$

$X$ is a binary predictor, $M$ is a continuous mediator, and $Y$ is a binary outcome. I then want to take the product (ab) of the paths:

$X \rightarrow M$ (a)

estimated using linear regression, and

$M \rightarrow Y$ (b)

estimated using logit regression. I was wondering what scale/metric ab will then have.